# Complex musical chords

Tags: music, musicology

For my thesis in musicology (somebody create that tag!) that is due this monday I need help figuring out how to achive notation of complex musical chords in Latex. I have tried every googable solution for stacking symbols in math mode and i have looked for packages that does this the right way, but alas... Lilypond is of no use either, as the chord notation there is ugly beyond belief (that being said, i love it for typesetting everything else).

Examples of my two attempts are pitiful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
C\(^{7}\dbinom{\sharp7}{\sharp5}\)

\end{document}
```

The first one does not format correctly at all, the second one is sort of right, but is HUMONGOUS and ugly.

What i need is what my notation program does, as seen in the bottom example.

I'm using Tufts class and lilyglyphs for musical symbols, compiling in LuaLatex.

[image: Example]

**Temporary solution**

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\tinysharpx}[1][0.10ex]{\hspace*{#1}\sharp[scale=.7]\hspace*{#1}} % Makes some room around the symbol and scales it down to better fit stacking
\newcommand{\tinyflatx}[1][0.10ex]{\hspace*{#1}\flat[scale=.7]\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand\bigchord[4]{\(\text{#1}^{#2}\mkern-3mu\relax(\mathop{}\limits\mkern-3mu\relax{}^{#3}_{#4})\)} % makes a four argument operator 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\bigchord{C}{7}{\tinysharpx 9}{\tinysharpx 5}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Still needs fixing**

1) Adjusting the lilypond symbol to become as tall as the number (as in the Sibelius example).

2) Adjusting the distance between the two stacked numbers. Needs to be a little bit tighter.

Comment: There, I created the "musicology" tag and added it to your posting. :-)

Comment: @Mico [tag:musicology]? Why?

Comment: @SeanAllred - To accommodate the OP. :-) The existing "music" tag seems too narrow to capture the posting's topic.

Comment: @Mico Much obliged. Musicologists need a place to geek out as well!

Comment: You should check out Music.SE :-) that said, @Mico I think [tag:music] is sufficient for TeX.SX -- I suppose time shall tell :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Perhaps, but this is specific to the academic and scientific branch of musicology, not music as such. As in: How to solve musical typography in latex. I firmly belive there is a comming need for musicology spesific latex packages and though some music forum is great for discussing music they dont know latex like you guys do.

Comment: @Buschmann oh naturally – I wasn't saying your question wasn't welcome :) but I don't think there are a lot of typography-related distinctions between music and musicology. At the end of the day, all you're doing is engraving the notation.

Comment: See also https://www.ctan.org/topic/music

Comment: @SeanAllred This is true, and i see your point, but its a bit like saying arithmetic and algebra is the same because its math. EDIT: Nice link! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24272/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-buschmann).

Comment: Monday?  Cutting it rather close, aren't you?  :-)  But these are some great solutions; my upvote button got worn out.

Comment: Have you tried `\Takt` from the `harmony` package?

Comment: Wow! That was supersexy! Thanks for the heads-up, will use for my functional analysis.

Comment: I'm happy to welcome another musicologist to the site! :)

Comment: What's wrong with using `tbinom` instead of `dbinom` ? `$\textup{C}\tbinom{\sharp 9}{\sharp 5}$` looks fine to me.

Comment: Indeed it does. Is there a way to controll the parenthesis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the following come close to what you need?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

C\(^{7}\hspace*{-.5ex}\binom{\sharp[scale=.6]7}{\sharp[scale=.6]5}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the actual size of the sharps and the space between the key and the parens may depend on the actual text font.

I think it would be a good idea to create a proper parametrization and think about making proper commands for chord symbols. The question is whether this should be integrated in `lilyglyphs` or if we should create a new package `chordsymbols`.

Comment: I think this looks quite good, but if we are going to make a package there is quite a bit more to do. Chords have different layers of complexity and need different operators depending on said complexity. See here: http://i.imgur.com/crR5239.png The most complex chord needed (at least that i can think of right now) is a "supercomplex" chord with "different root". I think you would need 6 operators to handle this. \chord{Dm}{7}{#9}{#9#5}{#11b9#5}{/C}. To make it super friendly one would have to program it so that when {/C} it is the last operator regardless. It could be part of Lilyglyphs!

Comment: @Buschmann Personally I think it would be best to make a new package that detects `lilyglyphs` usage. If someone will provide me a real basis for syntax, I'll try my hand at the coding. There is a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24272/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-buschmann) for this question for back/forth ideas.

Answer (score 14):

(Changed the code to work with clones of Palatino text and math fonts.)

The example below defines to helper macros named `\mraise` and `\mtop` -- short for "musicology-raise" and "musicology-atop", I suppose. The former uses two TeX "primitives" (`\raise` and `\hbox`) to raise its argument a bit *less* than `\textsuperscript` does. The latter uses still another TeX "primitive", `\atop`, to typeset its arguments quite compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}  % set the text and math fonts
\usepackage{mleftright}  \mleftright

%% Two handy macros: \mraise and \mtop

\newcommand\mraise[1]{\raise0.6ex\hbox{\scriptsize#1}}
\newcommand\mtop[2]{$\left(\mkern-1.5mu{{#1}\atop#2}\mkern-1.5mu\right)$}

\begin{document}
C\mraise{7}\mtop{\sharp9}{\sharp5}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's the result of the preceding clone, with the `mathpazo` package loaded instead of `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`, and with `\left` and `\right` in the `\mtop` macro replaced with `\bigl` and `\bigr`:

[image]

---

*A further update*, which uses LuaLaTeX, the `fontspec` package, the `lilyglyphs` font package, and three text font candidates (Computer Modern, a Times Roman clone, and a Palatino clone):

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}

%% Two helper macros: \mraise and \mtop
\newcommand\mraise[1]{\raise0.6ex\hbox{\scriptsize#1}}
\newcommand\mtop[2]{$\bigl(\mkern-1.5mu {{\scriptsize#1}\atop{\scriptsize#2}} \mkern-1.5mu\bigr)$}

\begin{document}

C\mraise{7}\mtop{\sharp9}{\sharp5} 

\setmainfont{XITS}
C\mraise{7}\mtop{\sharp9}{\sharp5} 

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
C\mraise{7}\mtop{\sharp9}{\sharp5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try this with `\large` or similar -- I think you'll find `\mraise` fails. Also, `mtpro2` doesn't seem to come with TeX Live, at least.

Comment: I will try this too. I use palatino -I think...- as parts of the `Tufts` class and `lilyglyphs` for musical symbols.

Comment: @Buschmann - I've changed the font family to Palatino.

Comment: @Mico "reason to believe..." Why not? I guess if it's only to be used in body text, this isn't too bad to manage manually. I do have to say those parens looked nice :)

Comment: I could not get `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` to work in my document, im afraid. The result is less then satisfying. http://i.imgur.com/RHXzA52.png I've emailed the lilyglyph creator to get an opinion on whether its possible to scale just the \sharp and \flats to make it comply.

Comment: @SeanAllred - I've changed the argument of `\raise` so that it should give workable results even with non-default font sizes.

Comment: @Buschmann - I've modified the code (changed the units in the argument of `\raise`) so that it should work with non-default font sizes. Please give it a try. If the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` font packages aren't on your system, please give it a new try with the `mathpazo` font package (both text and math font is a Palatino clone).

Comment: Tried with mathpazo, still no luck. http://i.imgur.com/7lnOrjZ.png

Comment: @Buschmann - Which TeX distribution do you have? The `mathpazo` package has been around for decades, I believe. If the `mathpazo` package is not available on your system, something may be amiss.

Comment: By the way, I know virtually nothing about musical notation. If my efforts look pitiful to you, it's because they are.

Comment: As far as i know i have the latest MacTex package. I think this has to do with lilyglyphs, because the MWE works just fine in a new document until i load that package. EDIT: They look wonderful and I'm very gratefull for you help :-)

Comment: Ah, just noticed that you updated your posting to mention that you use LuaLaTeX. Will post an updated version of the code that uses the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24274/discussion-between-buschmann-and-mico).

Comment: Do you notice that using `\setmathfont` will stop the `lilyglyphs` fonts to be used?

Comment: @uli_1973 - No, I had not. Glad you noticed and posted a more workable solution.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\thing[4]{$\text{#1}^{#2}\mkern-2mu\relax(\mathop{}\limits\mkern-2mu\relax{}^{#3}_{#4})$}

\begin{document}
\thing{C}{7}{\sharp 9}{\sharp 5}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm doing with `\mathop`.

Comment: Thank you for trying. The dimesions look right, but i cant get \sharp to work? EDIT: I was a idiot. Will try your new code.

Comment: @Buschmann if you tell me which package you used for that, I'll try it out. (At least, I *think* it's from a package. Honestly didn't try it.)

Comment: Thank you again for your time. Many musical symbols are part of Latex, in math mode use \sharp or \flat to activate them. If you want to get fancy, i use `lilyglyphs` to extend the symbols package. EDIT: I see you use "ordinary" sharps. How do i adjust it so that it uses \sharp insted?

Comment: @Buschmann you should just be able to replace it in the call.

Comment: Helps! I have NO idea what to change. Help a poor imbecile. `\newcommand\thing[4]{$\text{#1}^{#2}\mkern-2mu\relax(\mathop{}\limits\mkern-2mu\relax{}^{\sharp3}_{\flat4})$}`

Comment: @Buschmann XD http://i.imgur.com/Ksusqmq.gif take a look at the edit -- particularly, if you click the 'edited 1 minute ago' link thing, you'll be able to see exactly what I changed

Comment: I get this: http://i.imgur.com/kvvLXoh.png Your suggestion at the top, @Miko's at the bottom. Neither ideal. I wonder if the `lilyglyphs` package isnt scaling things right.

Comment: Comments aren't good for extended discussion -- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24272/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-buschmann

Comment: @Buschmann - What (absolute or relative) font size did you set for the screenshot you posted in the comment?

Comment: @Mico Alas, my solution isn't robust, either! I think it would be easier to user `stackengine` here -- If only I knew how to use it :)

Comment: `lilyglyph` normally scales things well, and if it doesn't fit in the context of the actual text font you can use the `[scale]` option.